# Is there a way to fetch multiple urls(chunks) from a web server with one GET request?

Tags: python, webserver, python-requests

I am using python requests right now but if there is a way to do this then it would be a game changer... Specifically i want to download a bunch of pdf's from one web site. I have the urls to the pages i want. Can i grab more then one at a time?

Comment: Does this one URL you are requesting contain all of the URLs you want in the page source/response? If so then with a bit of string manipulation you can, and I can help with that.

Comment: No. I already have the list of urls i need to download. All of the urls are located on different pages of the same website.

Comment: Then yes, if you are using threads then you can download them all at once. The time to download will be determined by your download speed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically Python APIs but, for sure, HTTP specification does not allow a single GET request to fetch multiple resources. To each request always corresponds one and only one resource in response. This is intrinsic of the protocol.
In some situations you have to do many request to obtain a single resource, or a part of it, as happens with range requests. But also in this case every request has only one response which is finally used by the client to assemble the complete final resource.